# Getting the error "declaration of DateTimeValue::make() should be compatible with"

Tags: php

Recently I have updated the PHP version in the our from PHP 5.3.3 to PHP 5.6.7.

After I upgraded the PHP version, I am getting the below error. Please suggest me how to solve this issue.

```
 Strict Standards: Declaration of DateTimeValue::make();

 Should be compatible with DateValue::make($month, $day, $year);
```

in `/home/mylocation/datetime/DateTimeValue.class.php on line 0`

Comment: Please show your class definition, and specifically the `::make()` method.

Comment: Please find the make method written in the class file.                     function make($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year) {
      return new DateTimeValue(mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year));
    }                                                                                                             So I need to copy and paste it with different name ?. Please suggest

Comment: I've already posted an answer so I'm not sure why you're commenting here :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the timezone before using this:

```
date_default_timezone_set();
```

Comment: How is the timezone relevant to a parser warning?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [`angie.library.datetime`](https://github.com/nopticon/pmanager/tree/master/activecollab/angie/classes/datetime), the definition of `DateTimeValue::make()` is:

```
make($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year)
```

Whereas the parent class definition is:

```
make($month, $day, $year)
```

The number of required arguments should be the same, because otherwise the substitution principle is broken. You would normally do this by making the last three arguments optional.

However, the function declarations are so wildly different that it's better to create a new function altogether, e.g. by giving it a different name:

```
function make2($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year)
```